# Change column header runtime in Ext.ux.TouchGridPanel

Tags: touch, extjs

In my mobile app, am showing report in grid structure using Ext.ux.TouchGridPanel.

I would like to change the column Name runtime. i.e after my data get refreshed i would like to change the column name.

In Ext JS it is done by something like this

```
 grid.getColumnModel().setColumnHeader(1, 'New Name');
```

But here grid(Ext.ux.TouchGridPanel) is derived from Ext.DataView, and no idea how to change the column header name after data refreshed/reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

First you specify id for the header.

On refresh call a function , in that function you can update heading by

```
Panel.dockedItems.get("HeadingId").setTitle("CustomHeading");
```